# call mutiple endpoint with the same baseurl using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an angular application with CRUD operations for which i need to make several api calls using angular. My question is, I have one api which connects me to one of the tables in my Database. I built one more api for another table. I am successful in making one call but not with multiple endpoints. Could someone help me in writing a one service to call multiple endpoints with the same base URL.Thanks in advance here is my code

one url : http://annie.mypc.com:8080/rs/sp/filedata/
other url: http://annie.mypc.com:8080/rs/sp/outputfiledata/

My Service:

```
var angular = require ('angular');

    function restService( $http ){
        console.log("serv1");

        var urlBase = 'http://annie.mypc.com:8080/rs/sp/',

        inputFileData = function() {
            console.log("into the function");
            return $http.get(urlBase + 'filedata/');
            };
        return {
            inputFileData:inputFileData
        };
var urlBase = 'http://annie.mypc.com:8080/rs/sp/',

        outputFileData = function() {
            console.log("into the function");
            return $http.get(urlBase + 'outputfiledata/');
            };
        return {
            outputFileData:outputFileData
        };
```

modified Service:

```
var urlBase = 'http://annie.mypc.com:8080/rs/sp/',

            inputFileData = function() {
                console.log("into the function");
                return $http.get(urlBase + 'filedata/');
                },
outputFileData = function() {
                console.log("into the function");
                return $http.get(urlBase + 'outputfiledata/');
                };
            return {
                inputFileData:inputFileData,
outputFileData :outputFileData 
            };
```

my controller:

```
    restService.inputFileData().then(function (response) {
                console.log("established");
                $scope.result = response.data;
            },
                function(){
                    console.log("fail");
            }); 
restService.outputFileData().then(function (response) {
                console.log("established connection");
                $scope.result1 = response.data;
            },
                function(){
                    console.log("fail");
            });
```

Comment: for now i am using above code i am not sure whether it is proper way of doing it or not

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks like it should work (other than the fact that you've declared `urlBase` twice in the same scope [but after a return statement?]). In light of this, allow me to simply suggest a couple best-practices; some official, and some learned.

**Factor out `BASE_URL` and other configuration into a constant**

This allows you to inject it wherever it's needed while only maintaining one source of truth.

```
angular.module('MyApp').constant('BASE_URL', 'http://annie.mypc.com:8080/rs/sp');

angular.module('MyApp').controller('FooCtrl', ['BASE_URL', function(BASE_URL){
    console.log(BASE_URL); //=> 'http://annie.mypc.com:8080/rs/sp'
}]);
```

**If your API is the only thing you interact w/ over the wire, write an `$http` wrapper**

I've found this to be a surprisingly common use case, and you can save yourself a lot of keystrokes by having such a wrapper service add in things like `BASE_URL` and common request headers for you.

```
angular.module('MyApp').service('http', ['$http', 'BASE_URL', function($http, BASE_URL){
    return {
        get(endpoint){ return $http.get(BASE_URL + endpoint); }
        post(endpoint, body){ return $http.post(BASE_URL + endpoint, body); }
        //...
    };
}]);

angular.module('MyApp').controller('BazCtrl', ['http', function(http){
    http.get('/foobar'); //fetches 'http://annie.mypc.com:8080/rs/sp/foobar'
}]);
```

You can extend this to create an RPC-like interface to your API (which I believe is what you're going for based on the language of your post).

```
angular.module('MyApp').service('API', ['http', function(http){
    return {
        inputFileData(){ return http.get('/filedata'); },
        outputFileData(){ return http.get('/outputfiledata'); },
        // ...
    };
}]);

angular.module('MyApp').controller('BarCtrl', ['$scope', 'API', function($scope, API){
    API.inputFileData().then(res=> {
        console.log('established');
        $scope.result = res.data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: I do not understand where we are declaring or warping the base URL

Comment: I am kind of new to this approach. Is there any other way of doing it instead of constant service? Thanks in advance

Comment: The base url is "declared" in the only place you see the string literal (`'http://...'`): in the registration of the constant. Again, doing this allows you to keep the source of truth for the url in a single location without junking up your app with global variables and other such hacks. When you need it, you inject it, as the examples in my response show